# Writing a function to get a string input

Tags: c++, string, input

I need a function to get a string input from the user. I don't want to to use `cin` because I only want return (`\r`) to mark the end of input. I've done the following:

```
std::string GetInput()
{
  std::string str = "\0";
  char ch;
  do
  {
    ch = getch();
    if(ch) str += ch;
    putch(ch);
  }
  while (ch!='\r');
  return str;
}
```

It works but I'm not quite satisfied with it as it doesn't fully support Backspace and Right/Left Arrow keyboard buttons. My question is, how can I get input from the user, without the use of `cin`, while giving the user a `cin`-like feeling (full keyboard support)?

Comment: Do you need this particular function or do you just want to get user input? If second, consider using `getline`, `cin` and so on.

Comment: @cdshines Thanks. I didn't know I could use `getline` to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in fact use `cin`:

```
std::string GetInput()
{
  std::string input;
  if (!std::getline(cin, input)) {
    // handle error here
  }
  return input;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Is there a way to separate the `getline` and `if` lines? (to call `getline` first and then check if it is not empty?) I tried `if(input)` after calling `getline` but got an error message saying I can't convert `input` to a boolean value.

Comment: `if (input.empty()) { ... }`